# How to install a powershell module manually from a powershell script

Tags: powershell, module

I have a PowerShell Module in `powowshell.psm1` which I want to install and have immediately available as the alias `pow`. My `install.ps1` copies the file to the correct folder, does `Import-Module -name PowowShell -Global -Alias pow` and then checks to see the command exists via alias with `Get-Command "pow"` which returns the command.

The problem is, as soon as `install.ps1` terminates the module is only available via the full name `Invoke-PowowShell` and not via the alas `pow`.

If I run the exact same `Import-Module` code afterwards, with or without `-Alias` I suddenly have `pow`.

Why is my module not immediately available as `pow` but only as `Invoke-PowowShell`.

Restarting PowerShell does not help.

**powowshell.psm1**

```bsh
function Invoke-PowowShell {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('pow')]
    #...code here...
    "You have the POWer!"
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function Invoke-PowowShell -Alias pow
```

**install.ps1**:

```bsh
    # Copy .psm1 to correct modules folder /PowowShell/PowowShell.psm1
    # ...
    # Install module globally
    Write-Verbose "Import-Module -name PowowShell -Global -Alias pow"
    Import-Module -name PowowShell -Global -Alias pow
    # Check we have the "pow" alias available
    write-verbose 'Get-Command "pow"'
    $PowowShell = Get-Command "pow"
    write-verbose "`$PowowShell=$PowowShell"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Installing PowowShell module to C:\Users\me\Documents\PowerShell\Modules ...
VERBOSE: Import-module -name PowowShell -Global
VERBOSE: Loading module from path
'C:\Users\me\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\PowowShell\PowowShell.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Invoke-PowowShell'.
VERBOSE: Exporting alias 'pow'.
VERBOSE: Importing alias 'pow'.
VERBOSE: Get-Command "pow"
VERBOSE: $PowowShell=pow
Yep, the 'pow' is CmdLet installed
 Type 'pow help' for a list of commands

PS W:\powershell\powowshell> pow help
pow : The term 'pow' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

PS W:\powershell\powowshell> Get-Command Invoke-PowowShell

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Invoke-PowowShell                                  0.0        PowowShell
```

So nothing works and then I manually `Import-Module`...

```
PS W:\powershell\powowshell> Import-Module -name PowowShell -Global
PS W:\powershell\powowshell> pow
"You have the POWer!"
```

Now it works!

Comment: did you try and add the module import to your profile?

Comment: No, is that required? I want an automated install process... Why is `Import-Module -Global` not respected inside my script but only outside?

Comment: not sure, just trying to help you debug. Might be you've run into this issue: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3352

Comment: It appears modules should be loaded automatically in PowerShell > v3 unless `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` is set to `none`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating a `.psd1` manifest which explicitly lists the alias.

Interestingly, PowerShell 5 works fine so I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3352) with PowerShell Core - I suspect they will say the "rule" is you must create a manifest.

**powowshell.psd1**:

```bsh
@{
RootModule = '.\powowshell.psm1'
#...
AliasesToExport = 'pow'
}
```